# EmEditorでGoogle IMEの再変換機能をマクロで自動化する方法はありますでしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorでGoogle IMEの再変換機能をマクロで自動化する方法はありますでしょうか？

お世話になっております。

Google IMEの再変換機能で1行ずつ自動で選択して再変換を繰り返すというマクロは可能でしょうか？

例文

「それに、たいしてまけるひとは、おおいので、
まけのげんいんをぶんせきすることは、いみが、ある。
ひとつひとつは、つまらないしっぱいでも、
あつめるとほうそくせいが、みえてくる。
にほんけいざいは、「ちょうきていたい」に、
はいったといわれ、そのげんいんは、
「せいさんせいがひくいからだ」とか
「いのべーしょんがたりないからだ」といわれる。」

このような短い文章が延々と続きます。

1行全部選択→再変換確定→次の行に移動して1行全文選択→再変換確定→これを延々と繰り返す

このように変換しやすい短く区切ったひらがな文をあらかじめマクロで作っておき、自動で最初から最後まで再変換→確定を繰り返すという方法です。

一発では正確にならず誤変換もありましたが、正確さより一発で自動的に最後まで変換していけることを希望しています。

Google IMEで手動ではかなりうまくいきました。

よろしくお願いいたします。

それに、大して負ける人は、多いので、
負けの原因を分析することは、意味が、ある。
一つ一つは、つまらない失敗でも、
集めると法則性が、見えてくる。
日本経済は、「長期停滞」に、
入ったと言われ、その原因は、
「生産性が低い体」とか
「イノベーションが足りないからだ」と言われる。」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変換エンジンを YahooAPI にして、変換ファイル名の変更と、文字数対策を追加してみました。

- マクロ利用法
  ・このマクロ本体は SJIS で保存。
  ・アプリケーションIDを取得してソースリスト先頭の Appid に設定する。
  https://e.developer.yahoo.co.jp/register
  例: [Yahoo! ID連携 v1] アプリケーションの種類 クライアントサイド（Yahoo! ID連携 v1）, 利用者情報 個人, アプリケーション名 <適当に>, サイトURL <無記入>, アプリケーションの説明  <無記入>, ガイドライン <同意する>
  ・目的のドキュメントを開いてマクロを実行する、変換終了時に自動で変換ファイルをオープンする。
- 仕様、制限
  ・Yahoo の仕様により一行の最大文字数は80文字(ひらがな換算時)まで
  かな漢字変換Web APIは、24時間以内で1つのアプリケーションIDにつき50000件のリクエストが上限 https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/appendix/rate.html
  ・一行単位で変換、
  一行の文字数が多い場合 "。↓▽▼" で分割して、それを最大文字数以内に収まる範囲で連結して処理、
  それでも文字数が多い場合 "、, " で更に分割して、それを最大文字数以内に収まる範囲で連結して処理、
  それでも最大文字数を超える場合 EmEditorのアウトプットバーに行番号を出力。
  ・出力はドキュメントのディレクトリにファイル名 "再変換済み　+{ドキュメントのファイル名}" として第一候補の連結文字列(一発変換)を出力。
  ・入出力は UTF-8

```
#title "one-hit wonder"
#tooltip "一括漢字変換"

var Appid = ""; // *** Yahoo APPID ***
var RequestWait = 200;      // リクエスト間隔制限
var SizeLimit = 80;         // 変換文字数制限

var flagOutputBar = OutputBar.Visible;
var recCount = 0;   // リクエスト回数カウンター

function putOutBar( num, mes ){
    OutputBar.Visible = true;
    OutputBar.writeln( num + ": " + mes );
    flagOutputBar = true;
}

// デベロッパーネットワークトップ > テキスト解析 > かな漢字変換
// https://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/jlp/jim/v1/conversion.html
function yahooApi( str ){
    if( Appid == "" )   return "";
    recCount ++;
//  return str + "||";          // DEBUG
    var rval = "";
    try {
        var uri = "https://jlp.yahooapis.jp/JIMService/V1/conversion";
        uri += "?appid=" + Appid;
        uri += "&sentence=" + encodeURIComponent( str );

        var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");
        xhr.open( "GET", uri, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "User-Agent", "EmEditor " + editor.Version + "; Yahoo AppID " + Appid );
//      xhr.setProxy( 2, "127.0.0.1:8080", "" );
        xhr.send();
        for( var rty = 1000; xhr.readyState != 4 && rty > 0; --rty ){ xhr.waitForResponse(100); }
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 ){
            if( xhr.status == 200 ){
                var dom = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
                dom.async = false;
                dom.loadXML( xhr.responseText );
                var segs = dom.getElementsByTagName("Segment");
                for( var i = 0; i < segs.length; i++ ) {
                    var para = segs[i].getElementsByTagName("Candidate");
                    rval += para[0].text;
                }
            } else if( xhr.status == 403 ){
                alert( "Web APIのリクエスト回数制限に到達、00:00にリセット" );
                ravl = "\x08";
            }
        } else {
            xhr.abort();
            alert( "Error abort" );
            ravl = "\x08";
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert( "Error( " + e.message + " )" );
        ravl = "\x08";
    }
    return rval;
}

// 簡易文節分割
function splitSeg( rg, str ){   // rg = /^(.*?[。↓▽▼])(.+)$/,  /^(.*?[、　 ])(.+)$/
    var para = [];
    var wrk = str;
    var m;
    while( m = wrk.match( rg ) ){
        if( m[1] != "" ){ para.push( m[1] ); }
        wrk = m[2];
    }
    if( wrk != "" ){ para.push( wrk ); }
    return para;
}

// 変換処理本体
function comv_main( strPath ){
    var fh = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    fh.Type = 2;
    fh.Charset = "UTF-8";
    fh.Open();

    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    for( var yPos = 1; yPos <= document.GetLines(); ++ yPos ){
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, yPos ); // 実行状況が分かるようにカーソルを動かす。無くても良い。
        var str = document.GetLine( yPos );
        var m = str.match( /^(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)$/ );
//      if( m != null && m[2] != "" ){
        if( m[2] != "" ){
            str = m[2];
//          alert( str.length );
            if( str.length >= SizeLimit ){
                var wrk = "";

                var para2 = splitSeg( /^(.*?[。↓▽▼])(.+)$/, str );       // 分割文字 '。','↓','▽','▼'
                var str3 = "";
                for( var i = 0; i < para2.length; ++ i ){
                    str3 += para2[i];
                    if( i+1 < para2.length && str3.length + para2[i+1].length < SizeLimit ){ continue; }

                    if( str3.length >= SizeLimit ){
                        var para3 = splitSeg( /^(.*?[、　 ])(.+)$/, str3 );       // 分割文字 '、','　',' '
                        var wrk4 = "";
                        for( var j = 0; j < para3.length; ++ j ){
                            wrk4 += para3[j];
                            if( j+1 < para3.length && wrk4.length + para3[j+1].length < SizeLimit ){ continue; }
                            if( wrk4.length >= SizeLimit ){
                                putOutBar( yPos, "SizeOver '" + wrk4 + "'" )
                            }
                            var yconv = yahooApi( wrk4 );
                            if( yconv == "\x08" ){ return; }    // Error
                            Sleep( RequestWait );
                            wrk4 = "";
                            wrk += yconv;
                        }
                    } else {
                        var yconv = yahooApi( str3 );
                        if( yconv == "\x08" ){ return; }    // Error
                        Sleep( RequestWait );
                        wrk += yconv;
                    }
                    str3 = "";
                }
                str = wrk;
            } else {
                var yconv = yahooApi( str );
                if( yconv == "\x08" ){ return; }    // Error
                Sleep( RequestWait );
                str = yconv;
            }
            fh.WriteText( m[1] + str + m[3], 1 );
        } else {
            fh.WriteText( "", 1 );
        }
    }
    fh.SaveToFile( strPath, 2 );
    fh.Close();
    return 0;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAIN
    var strPath = document.Path + "\\再変換済み　" + document.Name;
    OutputBar.Clear();
    OutputBar.Visible = true;
    var docReadOnly = document.ReadOnly;
    document.ReadOnly = true;

    comv_main( strPath );

    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    document.ReadOnly = docReadOnly;
    OutputBar.writeln( "\n*** API リクエスト回数 : " + recCount ); flagOutputBar = true;   // 不要ならこの行を削除
    if( ! flagOutputBar ){ OutputBar.Visible = false; }
    editor.OpenFile( strPath, 0, eeOpenAllowNewWindow );    // 変換ファイルを開く
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。たいへんお世話になっております。御厚意､感謝しております。素晴らしく理想的な動き方です。人名など固有名詞の正確さGoogle IMEのほうがレベルは高いようですが長い文章の文節を正しく一発変換するのはYahoo!かな漢字変換APIのほうが自然な文になっております。きょうじっくり検証してまた報告させて頂きます。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

[Google 日本語入力](https://www.google.co.jp/ime/cgiapi.html) を参照してドキュメント一発変換マクロを作ってみました。

- マクロ利用法
  目的のドキュメントを開いてマクロを実行する。
- 仕様、制限
  出力はドキュメントのディレクトリにファイル名 Gconv.txt (OutlPath) として第一候補の一発変換を保存する。
  入出力は UTF-8

```
var OutlPath = "Gconv.txt";

function googleConv( str ){
    var rval = "";
    try {
        var uri = "http://www.google.com/transliterate";
        uri += "?langpair=ja-Hira|ja";
        uri += "&text=" + encodeURIComponent( str );    // パーセントエンコード

        var xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");
        xhr.open( "GET", uri, true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "User-Agent", "EmEditor " + editor.Version );     // 必要のない設定
//      xhr.setProxy( 2, "127.0.0.1:8080", "" );
        xhr.send();
        for( var rty = 1000; xhr.readyState != 4 && rty > 0; --rty ){ xhr.waitForResponse(100); }
        if( xhr.readyState == 4 ){
            if( xhr.status == 200 ){ rval = xhr.responseText; }
        } else {
            xhr.abort();
            alert( "Error abort" );
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert( "Error( " + e.message + " )" );
    }
    return rval;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAIN
    var fs = new ActiveXObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" );
    var strPath = document.Path + "\\" + OutlPath;
    var fh = fs.OpenTextFile( strPath, 2, true, -1 );
    var docReadOnly = document.ReadOnly;
    document.ReadOnly = true;

    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    for( var yPos = 1; yPos <= document.GetLines(); ++ yPos ){
        var str = document.GetLine( yPos );
        var m = str.match( /^(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)$/ );
        if( m != null && m[2] != "" ){
            str = m[2];
            var gconv = googleConv(str);
            Sleep( 300 );
            if( gconv == "" )   break;  // Error
            var jdata = JSON.parse( gconv );
            str = "";
            for( var i = 0; i < jdata.length; ++ i ){
                str += jdata[i][1][0];
            }
            fh.WriteLine( m[1] + str + m[2] );
        } else {
            fh.WriteLine( "" );
        }
        document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosLogical, 1, yPos ); // 実行状況が分かるようにカーソルを動かす。無くても良い。
    }
    fh.Close();

    document.selection.StartOfDocument();
    document.ReadOnly = docReadOnly;
```

Comment: fh.WriteLine( m[1] + str + m[2] ); は
fh.WriteLine( m[1] + str + m[3] ); でした。

Comment: 作成いただきありがとうございます。
素晴らしくキレイに動いてくれました!
設定値よりかなり速くしても正常に動きました。

御厚意､感謝しております。

追加で質問させて頂きます。

●同一ファイル上書き保存する場合

●元のファイル名に付加した名前で保存するにはどうすれば可能でしょうか？

事例
北海道の旅行記録.txt
↓
再変換済み　北海道の旅行記録.txt

こんな感じで保存です。

●長すぎてスキップされた行はスキップエラーを出力して抜けた行に記載することは可能でしょうか？

現在、動作状況を検証しております。

検証した途中結果報告
Google IMEは、80文字までが最大認識数でした。それ以降の長い行の80字を超えた字は一切無視する仕様のようです。

ただ、変換する字が多い場合は、70文字でも変換できず抜けが生じてましたので1回当たり60文字以内にしておくのが無難そうでした。

またさらに追加で報告させて頂きます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 追記　60文字でも変換できずに消失する行がありました。一発の変換精度ではYahoo!かな漢字変換APIがもっとも長い文でも一発変換できる優秀なようです。

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft IME の利用法が分かったのでプログラムを書いてみました。
独立したアプリケーションとして動作します。
中心部分は参照した [Netplanetes Memo](https://www.pine4.net/Memo/Article/Archives/424) ほぼそのままです。

- 利用法
  汎用のテキスト処理プログラムにしましたが、コマンドプロンプトで実行する以外に、
  EmEditor のツールに、引数 `-k $(CurText)` とか `-k -f $(Path)` などとして、
  アウトプット バーを使用するにチェックすれば、選択文字やファイル全体の処理を EmEditor と連携できます。
- 仕様
  入力は [ 標準入力、コマンドライン、クリップボード、ファイル ] から選べて
  出力は [ 標準出力、クリップボード、ファイル ] から選べます。
  一発変換の変換精度は Microsoft IME の辞書次第です。

#### コンソール アプリ (.NET Framework)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;

namespace ImeConversion {
    // IFELanguage2 Interface ID
    //[Guid("21164102-C24A-11d1-851A-00C04FCC6B14")]
    [ComImport]
    [Guid( "019F7152-E6DB-11d0-83C3-00C04FDDB82E" )]
    [InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown )]
    public interface IFELanguage {
        int Open();
        int Close();
        int GetJMorphResult( uint dwRequest, uint dwCMode, int cwchInput, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPWStr )] string pwchInput, IntPtr pfCInfo, out object ppResult );
        int GetConversionModeCaps( ref uint pdwCaps );
        int GetPhonetic( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr )] string @string, int start, int length, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr )] out string result );
        int GetConversion( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr )] string @string, int start, int length, [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.BStr )] out string result );
    }

    class Program {
        static IFELanguage ifelang = null;

        [STAThread]
        // 漢字 -> ひらがな
        static private string immYomi( in string str )
        {
            string result;
            int hr = ifelang.GetPhonetic( str, 1, -1, out result );
            if( hr != 0 ) {
                throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR( hr );
            }
            return result;
        }

        // ひらがな -> 漢字
        [STAThread]
        static private string immKanji( in string str )
        {
            string result;
            int hr = ifelang.GetConversion( str, 1, -1, out result );
            if( hr != 0 ) {
                throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR( hr );
            }
            return result;
        }

        [STAThread]
        static int Main( string[] args )
        {
            var opt_k = false;  // -k 漢字変換     ひらがな -> 漢字 -k (変換文字列, -f ファイルパス)
            var opt_h = false;  // -h ひらがな変換 漢字 -> ひらがな -h (変換文字列, -f ファイルパス)
            var opt_co = false; // -co 結果をクリップボードへ出力
            var opt_ci = false; // -ci クリップボードから opt_str を設定
            var opt_f = "";     // -f ファイル変換 ファイルパス
            var opt_o = "";     // -o 出力 ファイルパス
            var opt_str = "";   // 変換元文字列
            Encoding fileEnc = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false );  // ファイルエンコーディング -utf8, -sjis, -eucjp
            for( int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++ i ) {
                bool f_last = (i >= args.Length - 1);
                var sOpt = Regex.Replace( args[i], "^/", "-" ).ToLower();
                if( sOpt == "-k" ) {    opt_k = true;
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-h" ) {    opt_h = true;
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-sjis" ) { fileEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding( "Shift_JIS" );
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-utf8" ) { fileEnc = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false ); ;
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-eucjp" ) {fileEnc = Encoding.GetEncoding( "euc-jp" );
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-co" ) {   opt_co = true;
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-ci" ) {   opt_ci = true;
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-f" && ! f_last ) {    opt_f = args[++i];
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-o" && ! f_last ) {    opt_o = args[++i];
                } else
                if( sOpt == "-?" ) { // Help
                    opt_k = opt_h = opt_co = opt_ci = false;
                    opt_str = opt_f = "";
                    break;
                } else
                if( f_last ) {
                    opt_str = args[i];
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine( " option ? : " + args[i] );
                    opt_k = opt_h = opt_co = opt_ci = false;
                    opt_str = opt_f = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( opt_ci ) {
                opt_str = Clipboard.GetText();
            }
            if( ! (opt_k ^ opt_h) || (opt_str == "" && opt_f == "") || (opt_ci && opt_f != "") ) {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Usage: (-k,-h) [-utf8,-sjis,-eucjp] [-o file path] (string, -f file path)\n" +
                    " -k : ひらがな -> 漢字\n" +
                    " -h : 漢字 -> ひらがな\n" +
                    " -ci : クリップボード から変換元を取得\n" +
                    " -co : 結果をクリップボードへ出力\n" +
                    " -f file path : 変換元のファイルパス、'-f stdin:'で標準入力\n" +
                    " -o file path : -f|-ci 指定時の出力ファイルパス、指定しなければ標準出力。エンコードは入力ファイルの設定に合わせる\n" +
                    " -utf8,-sjis,-eucjp : 変換元のファイルのエンコード。省略時は utf8\n" +
                    " \"string\" : 変換元の文字列\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "  -k,-h どちらか一方だけを必ず指定\n" +
                    "  -utf8,-sjis,-eucjp 最も最後の指定が有効\n" +
                    "  string, -ci, -f file path どれかを必ず指定\n" +
                    "  string を指定する場合は必ず最後に指定、これ以外のオプションは順不同"
                );
                return 1;
            }

            try {
                ifelang = Activator.CreateInstance( Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "MSIME.Japan" ) ) as IFELanguage;   // "MSIME.Japan.FELang", "MSIME.Japan"
                int hr = ifelang.Open();
                if( hr != 0 ) {
                    throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR( hr );
                }
                if( opt_f == "" ) {
                    var str = ( opt_h )? immYomi( opt_str ) : immKanji( opt_str );
                    if( opt_co ) {
                        Clipboard.SetText( str );
                    } else
                    if( opt_o != "" ) {
                        using( StreamWriter fh = new StreamWriter( opt_o, false, fileEnc ) ) {
                            fh.WriteLine( str );
                        }
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine( str );
                    }
                } else {
                    bool f_stdin = (opt_f.ToLower() == "stdin:");
                    if( ! File.Exists( opt_f ) && ! f_stdin ) {
                        Console.WriteLine( "指定されたファイルが見つかりません。 '" + opt_f + "'" );
                        return 1;
                    }
                    bool f_cons = (opt_o == "" && ! opt_co);
                    var memBuf = new MemoryStream();
                    var conEnc = Console.OutputEncoding;
                    if( conEnc == Encoding.UTF8 ) {
                        conEnc = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false );    // BOMなし
                    }
                        using( var sr = (f_stdin)? Console.In : new StreamReader( opt_f, fileEnc ) ) {
                        StreamWriter writer =
                        ( f_cons )?
                        new StreamWriter( Console.OpenStandardOutput(), conEnc ) :
                        ( ( opt_co )?
                            new StreamWriter( memBuf ) :
                            new StreamWriter( opt_o, false, fileEnc )
                        );
                        writer.AutoFlush = true;

                        var line = "";
                        var str = "";
                        var no = 1;
                        while( (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null ) {   // 行単位で処理
                            str = (line.Trim() == "")?
                                "" :
                                ( (opt_h)? immYomi( line ) : immKanji( line ) );
                            writer.WriteLine( str );
                            if( ! f_cons ) {
                                Console.Write( no.ToString() + "\r" );
                            }
                            ++no;
                        }

                        if( opt_co ) {
                            writer.Flush();
                            Clipboard.SetText( Encoding.UTF8.GetString( memBuf.ToArray() ) );
                        }
                        if( ! f_cons ) {
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch( COMException ex ) {
                Console.WriteLine( "*** Error!! ***\n  " + ex.Message );
                return 1;
            } finally {
                if( ifelang != null ) ifelang.Close();
                ifelang = null;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
// 参照
// Microsoft IME の IFELanguage を使用して 読み仮名から漢字、漢字から読み仮名変換を行う簡易プログラム - Netplanetes
//    https://www.pine4.net/Memo/Article/Archives/424
//
```

- ビルド手順

Visual Studio 2019 辺りで、新規に C# のコンソ－ルアプリ(.NET Framework) のプロジェクトを作成 (プロジェクト名は ImeConversion など適当に)
Program.cs に上のソースを入れ替えて、namespace をプロジェクト名に合わせて書き換えて、他は標準設定のままでもビルドできます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。動作させてみます。また、その後にコメントさせて頂きます。書いて頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: お世話になっております。
ATOKでもできるようになってそうな感じはします。
https://www.atok.com/useful/valueup/direct/index_ver31.html

https://www.atok.com/useful/developer/api/summary_ver31.html#spec

Comment: それは ATOKの辞書(変換機能)を手元の情報からプログラムで拡張する為の物ですね。ATOKの機能を外部から利用する物では無い様です。

Comment: 理解致しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: お世話になっております。MSIMEと同様にATOKには、連携の仕様は付いてますでしょうか？

Comment: お世話になっております。Visual Studio 2019 Enterpriseをいれたので使わせて頂きます。Microsoft IMEは精度が低いだろうと思ってましたが、最近のバージョンアップでなかなかの変換精度でした。固有名詞ではATOKを上回る感じですMicrosoft IMEは適度に文章を短くしたほうが精度が良いようです。

Comment: お世話になっております。ありがとうございます。ビルドしようとするとエラー CS0103 現在のコンテキストに 'Clipboard' という名前は存在しません というエラーが出るのですが何が考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: 間違った表現になっていたので修正しました。C# コンソールアプリケーション -> コンソール アプリ (.NET Framework) です。前者だと .NET Core になるんですね。